# How to export the results of python to a txt file

Tags: python, export

I want to the results of my code to a "txt" file. SO far this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
mozilla_path = r"C:\Users\ivrav\Python38\geckodriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=8Cuk5vYAAAAJ&hl=en")
driver.maximize_window()
years = [element.get_attribute("textContent") for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="gsc_g_t"]')]
citations = [element.get_attribute("textContent") for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="gsc_g_al"]')]
for year, citation in zip(years, citations):
    print(year, citation)
```

I want to export these results to a "txt" file, and I was pursuing it in the following way

```
task= open("C:\Deutsche Bundesbank\Bundesbank.txt","a")
print (task.write("Deutsche Bundesbank Researchers and Citations\n"))
print(task.write(year, citation))
task.close()
```

Many thanks,
Best regards,
Iván

Comment: `task.write(str(year) + ' ' + str(citation))`

Comment: Hi! I think  the problem is that the code does not recognize  
´´´
print(task.write(year, citation))´
´´´
The code throws this mistake
´´´
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ivrav/PycharmProjects/Google Scholar/Task.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(task.write(year, citation))
TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: `write()` method takes a single argument of string type. you are giving two

Comment: Many thanks, dead shot! The command task.write(str(year) + ' ' + str(citation)) helped me, however on the txt file just appears the  last  year and citation number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with` to safely work with file handles. Also, you'll want to loop over the output and write line-by-line. No need to close the file handle within the `with`.

```
with open("C:\Deutsche Bundesbank\Bundesbank.txt","w") as file_handle:
    file_handle.write("Deutsche Bundesbank Researchers and Citations\n"))
    for year, citation in zip(years, citations):
        file_handle.write(str(year) + ' ' + str(citation))
```